# how fix NoReverseMatch at x?

Tags: python, html, django

I am getting the error NoReverseMatch at /post/(post number) when I am trying to enter post_detail.html

the error is Reverse for 'post_remove' not found. 'post_remove' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I guess I should change url of post_remove in urls.py but I don't know how

It is views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView

from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm


# Create your views here.


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})


def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})


def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})


def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})


def post_draft_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__isnull=True).order_by('created_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_draft_list.html', {'posts': posts})


def post_publish(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post.publish()
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=pk)


def post_remove(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post.delete()
    return redirect('post_list')
```

It is urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    path('post/new/', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/edit/', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
    url(r'^drafts/$', views.post_draft_list, name='post_draft_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/publish/$', views.post_publish, name='post_publish'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$', views.post_remove, name='post_remove'),
]
```

It is post_detail.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="post">
        {% if post.published_date %}
            <div class="date">
                {{ post.published_date }}
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'post_publish' pk=post.pk %}">Publish</a>
        {% endif %}

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'post_edit' pk=post.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'post_remove' pk=post.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
        {% endif %}
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

It is base.html

```
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>J2KB's Web</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="page-header">
           {% if user.is_authenticated %}
           <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
           <a href="{% url 'post_draft_list' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
           {% endif %}

           <h1><a href="/">J2KB Web</a></h1>
       </div>
       <div class="content container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    {% block content %}
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

[it is error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vcv2.png)

Comment: I think you dont hav the id-5 in your database

Comment: I had the post in my database. is there other way to call the post id?

Comment: U did not render your post delete view thats why its stating invalid view function. Other than that the your pattern looks fine.